# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 - Updating maven repository index authentication failure

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-2, intellij-13

When I want to update indices from the central Maven repository, I always get an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Authorization exception retrieving nexes-maven-repository-index.properties.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693).

The workaround is to disable an option to **Use Maven 3** in IDEA `Settings` | `Maven` | `Importing`.

Another workaround is to [replace Maven jars](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122485#comment=27-706385) in IDEA distribution with more recent versions.

Original problem will be fixed in IDEA 13.1.2 (to be released soon).

Comment: I used the "replace Maven jars" approach, and it works. Thanks again.

Comment: For future reference: I disabled the option "Use Maven 3" and it worked for me.

Comment: Still not fixed in 13.1.3 :(

Comment: @makovkastar This specific issue is fixed, if you still have a problem, please submit another bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: This is fixed for me in 13.1.3, after upgrading from 13.1.1 (where the Maven 3 checkbox fix did not work). Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCoder It still not fixed in version 14.0.1

Comment: Same issue with 15.0.3 community edition. There is no such option in this version Use Maven 3 in IDEA Settings | Maven | Importing, and change to use my local Maven 3.3.3 still doesn't work.

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.2

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2

Comment: Same issue with IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4