# Maven configuration in IntelliJ yields authorization exception

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Backstory: I have a total of 30 minutes of maven usage experience, so it's safe to say I'm a newbie. I've successfully added a JUnit reference, but as soon as I tried adding the following, problems started mounting up in IntelliJ:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Both groupId and artifactId rendered in red color with the error text "dependencey (...) not found". I then checked the Maven configuration in IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1, which shows a red error box:

[image: IntelliJ settings showing java.io.IOException: Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties]

Where do I go from here? Why is there not an "Add" button to add other repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and is supposed to be fixed in release 13.1.2. There are a couple workarounds detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694939/407249.

The simplest solution is to uncheck the highlighted option shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: The problem still remains in the current Intellij. But the frame drawn here has o such field anymore....