# eclipse uses a wrong user id in the path to the Gradle cached library

Tags: eclipse, gradle-eclipse

I installed the Gradle plugin, imported a Gradle/Groovy project into eclipse, but found all import statement has this error: [Groovy Gradle"Project is missing required library" error in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095232/groovy-gradleproject-is-missing-required-library-error-in-eclipse)

Then I found, as you can see below, it's using id 'jironghu' instead of my real domain id 'huj', therefore causes all the jars missing. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the project was generated in another company where my id was different.